# What is a synonym for "feature"?

Tags: synonyms

Sometimes, I feel like the word "feature" is used far to often and sometimes it feels like there are no synonyms to this word. Are there any synonyms for *feature*?

Comment: context please?

Comment: What's your research show?

Comment: Try a _thesaurus_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context, as always, matters.

If you are referring to **feature** as in a computer program (such as *"up to 10x faster than the previous version!"*), you could try substituting with **benefits**.

If you are referring to **feature** as in a tangible characteristic like geographical topology (as in *"that's a tall mountain"*), or an intangible characteristic (as in *"he has a sad face"*), you could substitute it with a word denoting its **quality** directly, such as **looming** or **morose**.

Answer (score 0):

I would use aspect, quality, characteristic, trait, or component for a noun. For a verb, I would use present, promote, or highlight.

Answer (score -1):

Characteristic or quality would be very near to feature.